# AngularJs Create table

Tags: html, angularjs

So I want to create a table something similar to this

[image]

with this data

```
$scope.data = [
   {question : 1, answer : a},
   {question : 1, answer : b},
   {question : 1, answer : c},
   {question : 2, answer : b},
   {question : 2, answer : a},
   {question : 3, answer : c},
]
```

So far this is what i have

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" ng-init="current=null">
  <tr>
    <td><span ng-if="current != value.question">{{value.question}}</span></td>
    <td>{{value.answer}}</td>
    <td class="hidden">{{ current = value.question }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

would be glad if you could help and enlighten me thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your `$scope.data` first:: provide `""` for key.
Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Upal_Roy/vpu5py1e/)

```
$scope.data = [
   {"question" : 1, "answer" : "a"},
   {"question" : 1, "answer" : "b"},
   {"question" : 1, "answer" : "c"},
   {"question" : 2, "answer" : "b"},
   {"question" : 2, "answer" : "a"},
   {"question" : 3, "answer" : "c"}
]
```

View:
instead of use `ng-if` use `ng-show` for maintaining the structure of table.

```
<table>
 <tbody ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
  <tr>
    <td ng-show="data[key-1].question != value.question">{{value.question}}</td>
    <td>{{value.answer}}</td>
    <td class="hidden">{{ current = value.question }}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have there in data is an array of objects, and you are using the syntax for looping over objects and not arrays in your ng-repeat.

Just change like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Question#</th>
    <th>Answer#</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="value in data" >
    <tr>
      <td><span>{{value.question}}</span></td>
      <td>{{value.answer}}</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/2zzp0k0t/1/) to get you on your way.

Comment: will this generate the table structure like i posted above? thanks